# Creating a stepped seek bar

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I create a stepped seek bar for an android interface, one that functions like the seek bar in the menu below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) widget with some clever graphics. The other option is to Make your own widget, maybe starting with a subclass of [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) and implementing some sort of snapping to integer values (in the change listener).

Answer (score 0):

Subclass http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html